# Parsing JSONSchema to struct type in golang

Tags: go, struct, runtime

So, my use case consists of parsing varying JSON schemas into new struct types, which will be further used with an ORM to fetch data from a SQL database. Being compiled in nature, I believe there will not be an out-of-the-box solution in go, but is there any hack available to do this, without creating a separate go process. I tried with reflection, but could not find a satisfactory approach.

Currently, I am using [a-h generate](https://github.com/a-h/generate) library which does generate the structs, but I am stuck at how to load these new struct types in go runtime.

**EDIT**

Example JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Address",
  "id": "Address",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "address",
  "properties": {
    "houseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "House Name",
      "maxLength": 30
    },
    "houseNumber": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "House Number",
      "maxLength": 4
    },
    "flatNumber": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Flat",
      "maxLength": 15
    },
    "street": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Address 1",
      "maxLength": 40
    },
    "district": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Address 2",
      "maxLength": 30
    },
    "town": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "City",
      "maxLength": 20
    },
    "county": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "County",
      "maxLength": 20
    },
    "postcode": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Postcode",
      "maxLength": 8
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in the above-mentioned library, there is a command line tool, which generates the text for struct type for above json as below:

```
// Code generated by schema-generate. DO NOT EDIT.

package main

// Address address
type Address struct {
  County string `json:"county,omitempty"`
  District string `json:"district,omitempty"`
  FlatNumber string `json:"flatNumber,omitempty"`
  HouseName string `json:"houseName,omitempty"`
  HouseNumber string `json:"houseNumber,omitempty"`
  Postcode string `json:"postcode,omitempty"`
  Street string `json:"street,omitempty"`
  Town string `json:"town,omitempty"`
}
```

Now, the issue is that how to use this struct type without re-compilation in the program. There is a hack, where I can start a new go process, but that doesn't seem a good way to do it. One other way is to write my own parser for unmarshalling JSON schema, something like:

```
b := []byte(`{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}`)
var f interface{}
json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
m := f.(map[string]interface{})
for k, v := range m {
    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
    case float64:
        fmt.Println(k, "is float64", vv)
    case int:
        fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
        for i, u := range vv {
            fmt.Println(i, u)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest some pointers to look for. Thanks.

Comment: There's a number of ways to handle variadic schemas in golang. It's kind of hard to comment on what you can/can't/shouldn't do without seeing the actual data, or for that matter, what you've tried so far

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem My bad, I should have added it earlier. Can you suggest something now, please?

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Unmarshal, marshal? How many different types have you got to content with? Are there any fields in particular that all data has in common (eg schema, title, type, ...) that you can use? Have you looked in to creating your own type + implement  JSONMarshaller and JSONUnmarshaller interfaces on that? Have you looked at the RawMessage type, and considered using custom marshalling effectively doing the marshalling in 2 stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you're trying to implement your own json marshalling. That's no biggie: the standard json package already supports that. Just have your type implement the `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` functions (cf first example on [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)). Assuming some fields will be shared (eg schema, id, type), you can create a unified type like this:

```
// poor naming, but we need this level of wrapping here
type Data struct {
    Metadata
}

type Metadata struct {
    Schema string `json:"$schema"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Id string `json:"id"`
    Properties json.RawMessage `json:"properties"`
    Address *Address `json:"-"`
    // other types go here, too
}
```

Now all properties will be unmarshalled into a `json.RawMessage` field (essentially this is a `[]byte` field). What you can do in your custom unmarshall function now is something like this:

```
func (d *Data) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    meta := Metadata{}
    // unmarshall common fields
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &meta); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Assuming the Type field contains the value that allows you to determine what data you're actually unmarshalling
    switch meta.Type {
    case "address":
        meta.Address = &Address{} // initialise field
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(meta.Properties), meta.Address); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    case "name":
        meta.Name = &Name{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(meta.Properties), meta.Name); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    default:
        return errors.New("unknown message type")
    }
    // all done
    d.Metadata = meta // assign to embedded
    // optionally: clean up the Properties field, as it contains raw JSON, and is exported
    d.Metadata.Properties = json.RawMessage{}
    return nil
}
```

You can do pretty much the same thing for marshalling. First work out what type you're actually working with, then marshal that object into the properties field, and *then* marhsal the entire structure

```
func (d Data) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var (
        prop []byte
        err error
    )
    switch {
    case d.Metadata.Address != nil:
        prop, err = json.Marshal(d.Address)
    case d.Metadata.Name != nil:
        prop, err = json.Marshal(d.Name) // will only work if field isn't masked, better to be explicit
    default:
        err = errors.New("No properties to marshal") // handle in whatever way is best
    }
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    d.Metadata.Properties = json.RawMessage(prop)
    return json.Marshal(d.Metadata) // marshal the unified type here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I needed.